# Java Android getApplicationContext() returning a null object from previous class

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pass a user from one java class to another using getApplicationContext(). Unfortunately it is not working and is returning null.  I wish to pass the user information to from the LoginActivity  to the CustomMapActivity. The users infromation is stored in  firebase, could this be an issue?

I believe the manifest is in order. please see below.

```
  <activity android:name=".ui.MapCustomActivity"></activity>
     <activity android:name=".ui.LoginActivity">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
     </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ui.RegisterActivity" />
     <activity android:name=".ui.ProfileActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ui.MapCustomActivity"></activity>
```

Below is LoginActivity,

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener
      {
       @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.email);
        mPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
        mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        setupFirebaseAuth();
        findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.link_register).setOnClickListener(this);

        hideSoftKeyboard();
    }




    private void showDialog(){
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    private void hideDialog(){
        if(mProgressBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }




      private void setupFirebaseAuth(){
        Log.d(TAG, "setupFirebaseAuth: started.");

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                //user = null;
                if (user != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getEmail());
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authenticated with: " + user.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                    FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
                            .setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true)
                            .build();
                    db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);

                    DocumentReference userRef = db.collection(getString(R.string.collection_users))
                            .document(user.getUid());

                    userRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: successfully set the user client." + task.getResult());
                                User user = task.getResult().toObject(User.class);
                                ((UserClient)(getApplicationContext())).setUser(user);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MapCustomActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
                // ...
            }
        };
      }
```

Below is the MapCustomActivity:

```
public class MapCustomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_custom);

        photoview2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.limerickMapImageView);
         mAvatarImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageChooseAvatar);

        photoview2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
                view.bringToFront();
                viewTransformation(view, event);
                return true;
            }
        });
        retrieveProfileImage();

    }
     private void retrieveProfileImage(){
        RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions()
                .error(R.drawable.cwm_logo)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.cwm_logo);

        int avatar = 0;

        try{

            avatar = Integer.parseInt(((UserClient)getApplicationContext()).getUser().getAvatar());
        }catch (NumberFormatException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "retrieveProfileImage: no avatar image. Setting default. " + e.getMessage() );
        }

        Glide.with(MapCustomActivity.this)
                .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
                .load(avatar)
                .into(mAvatarImage);
    }
```

Below is the UserClient class

```
public class UserClient extends Application {

    private User user = null;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need pass your user when start your Activity, use Bundle for extras

Comment: Sorry Christopher, I dont understand what you mean. Could you expand a bit more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Pass Data From One Activity to Other Activity Using Intent, Make Sure you did following steps.

- Step 1 Create a New Explicit or Implicit Intent object in source 
  activity.
- Step 2 Call **intent.putExtra(String key, Object data)** method to save data in it.
- Step 3 Call startActivity(intent) method in source activity to pass the intent to android os.
- Step 4 Call getIntent() method in target activity.

In you case I think you are missed **Step 2**

Answer (score 0):

You're using getApplicationContext but maybe you were trying to use [getApplication](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getApplication()) method from Activity.
I don't recommend using this approach to pass objects from one activity to another. You should use the Intent object. Take a look at [the official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Do you can use a `bundle` to give the information between activities

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("value_name", 0);// 0 = value
bundle.putString("value_name", "text"); // Text = value string

Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivty.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

and catch in your second activity

```
public class SecondActivty extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_activty);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    int value = savedInstanceState.getInt("value_name");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current Activity, create a new Intent:

```
String value="Hello world";
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);    
i.putExtra("key",value);
startActivity(i);
```

Then in the new Activity, retrieve those values:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("key");
    //The key argument here must match that used in the other activity
}
```

With this technique you will be able to pass variables in an activity

Comment: And avoid using getApplicationContext as it might return null sometimes as in your case.